# Максим, просто (,) неужели это настолько сложно?

Tags: пунктуация

Максим, просто (,) неужели это настолько сложно?

Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

Comment: Хотелось бы понять смысл это этого высказывания. Я могу представить "просто" в роли частицы, но не в вопросительном предложении и не в стыке с "неужели".

Comment: Ну это вопрос на высказывание типа: "мало кто бегает по утрам... и тд"
И человек задает такой вопрос мне. Он не понимает, почему так происходит. 
Максим, просто (,) неужели это настолько сложно?
Хотелось бы понять, конкретно в данном предложении (пускай оно и неверно построено), но есть тут запятая или нет?

Comment: Не может быть "просто" в таком вопросе. Найдите хоть один бесспорный пример подобного. Или сами придумайте. У меня не получается. Вы только троллей кормите такими вопросами.

Comment: @behemothus подобный вариант распространен в повседневной речи (особенно в английской с аналогом *just*). Например, человеку настолько надоело все объяснять, что он с театральным закатыванием глаз говорит: "Максим, просто...". В таких случаях обычно предложение не продолжается.

Comment: *(особенно в английской с аналогом just)* - Еще не хватало нам тут английским заниматься. ))) А вам стоит внимательнее относиться к тому, что критикуете. Я говорил про **вопросы** с частицей "просто" - а этого даже в английском нет и быть не может. Это частица усилительная, снимающая  сомнения, а вы  с Максимом  предлагаете её в вопрос пихать?

Comment: @Persona Если это передача устной речи с недоговоркой (просто скажите...), зачем пытаться пристыковать к этому "просто" нестыкуемое? И так ясно, что человек запнулся - уж лучше начинать следующее предложение.

Comment: Если это "недоговорка", то нужно многоточие, а не запятая.

Comment: @behemothus критикую? Ну даете! :) Я с Вами совершенно согласен, а мое сообщение -- просто добавление.

Comment: @Alex_ander, технический момент. Писать "@Persona" бессмысленно. Нужен полный ник (без пробелов), тогда послание гарантировано найдет адресата.

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata - один черт, благожелательно или нет. Все равно надо быть внимательнее. Или корректнее в словах, если вы действительно не возражали мне. Внешне это выглядит как возражение. *Я не о вежливости (не на неё в обще-то наплевать), а именно о корректности в формулировках.*

Answer (score 1):

**Максим, просто** (= попросту) **неужели это настолько сложно?**

Это частица (так как произносится **без паузы**), но близкая по значению **к вводному слову** (= если рассуждать просто, прямо, без затей).  Можно считать, что это особенности **разговорного** стиля. Слово часто встречается в речи, но при этом не выделяется паузами.

**Примеры сочетаний "неужели просто":** Неужели просто совпадение? Неужели просто весна? Обычно это ответные реплики. В приведенном предложении "просто" по смыслу относится ко всему высказыванию.

Из словаря

ПОПРОСТУ. II. частица. **Просто**, просто-напросто. Он п. лжёт. Не болен, а п. устал.

Comment: То есть запятой там нет? Или есть? Я так и не понял)

Comment: После "просто" не нужна запятая,  нет паузы.

Comment: Посмотрела Ваш ответ на комментарий к вопросу. Максим, просто, неужели это настолько сложно?  Думаю,  что в частном случае, в "неправильно построенной" (неполной)  речи  выделение запятыми возможно. Тогда это "просто" обозначает: Максим, если говорить попросту, неужели это настолько сложно. Если Вы это слово  выделяете паузами в речи, то на письме надо выделить запятыми.

Answer (score 0):

> Просто мне утверждают, что фраза верная и там нет запятой. Хотелось бы прояснить этот вопрос. Так как говорят, что Word не прав

Максим,
а) Фраза неверная стилистически абсолютно.
б) Грамматически - не совсем корректная.
в) Запятой там нету, если вообще можно говорить о правильном пунктуационном оформлении столь сомнительного (семантически, стилистически и грамматически) высказывания. "Просто" в значении частицы запятой не требует.
г) Word - неправ. Даже не знаю, что он там вам сказал, но он всё равно неправ. Не тот источник, которому стоит уделять внимание.